# JQuery to parse RSS feed in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, rss

I m trying to display RSS data on page using jQuery, So I have used below URL in my code and it is working fine to display feed from outside SharePoint sites.

> "https://feed.jquery-plugins.net/load?url=" +
>   encodeURIComponent("feedURL") + "&maxCount=" + def.MaxCount +
>   "&dateCulture=" + def.DateFormatLang + "&dateFormat=" +
>   def.DateFormat"

But in SharePoint, this is giving error.

> {"statusCode":400,"errorMessage":"ERROR_ON_GETTING_FEEDS : '>' is an
>   unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 11, position
>   72.","data":null}

url for SharePoint is:

> url:
>   "https://feed.jquery-plugins.net/load?url=https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/DeveloperSite/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=f3d7161e-2f6d-4c6e-8d7d-1721e8b70ef0&View=5d658d21-4804-47d9-b993-0752aeb8feb5",

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you do what you want to do.

Here, you retrieve the output of an RSS reader. 
This Rss Reader reads for you files/stream that it can read : **public rss feed**.

Yours is private, and this tool have no access to it.

If you want to read rss, put this snippet on your page instead :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//feed to parse
var feed = "https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/DeveloperSite/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=f3d7161e-2f6d-4c6e-8d7d-1721e8b70ef0&View=5d658d21-4804-47d9-b993-0752aeb8feb5";

$.ajax(feed, {
    accepts:{
        xml:"application/rss+xml"
    },
    dataType:"xml",
    success:function(data) {
        //Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943544/how-to-parse-an-rss-feed-using-javascript

        $(data).find("item").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
            var el = $(this);
            console.log("------------------------");
            console.log("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
            console.log("link       : " + el.find("link").text());
            console.log("description: " + el.find("description").text());
        });


    }   
});
```

});

Source : https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/12/08/parsing-rss-feeds-in-javascript-options

you can go with more modern javascript (and less jquery) as well ;) => source :
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/rss-reader-in-javascript/

Comment: so how do we get top 5 results in this case? or to filer it by modified date

Comment: listfeed.aspx is not a rest endpoint, you cannot make a odata request on it.

You can filter after retrieve your data, or choose another endpoint like https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/DeveloperSite/_api/web/Lists('f3d7161e-2f6d-4c6e-8d7d-1721e8b70ef0')/items?$top=5 
(f3d7161e-2f6d-4c6e-8d7d-1721e8b70ef0 is your list ID)


https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the list RSS Feed in SharePoint page, we can use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=f3d7161e-2f6d-4c6e-8d7d-1721e8b70ef0&View=5d658d21-4804-47d9-b993-0752aeb8feb5",
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/rss+xml",
        },
        dataType:"xml",
        success: function (data){
            $(data).find("item").each(function () {          
                var html="<p><a href='"+$(this).find("link").text()+"'>"+$(this).find("title").text()+"</a><br/>";
                html+=""+$(this).find("description").text()+"</p>";
                $("#showListRSSFeed").append(html);
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert("Error");
        }
    }); 
})
</script>
<div id="showListRSSFeed"/>
```

If you want to access SharePoint list RSS Feed in external site, the code will not works, SharePoint online don't allow you anonymous access list RSS Feed.

Comment: can we also apply filters in url?

Comment: You can filter the data in the success method, we can't add the $filter like in REST API in listfeed.aspx request.